# Github Readme.Md dropdown (<details> and <summary>) not appearing correctly in github pages

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following in `my ReadMe.md`

```
### Adding a student: `student -a`
<details><summary>Adds a student to the students list.</summary>

Format: `student -a -n NAME [-c CONTACT] [-em EMAIL] [-s DAY/STARTTIME/ENDTIME]​`

* Adds a student with the specified `NAME`
* `-a` refers to the add command
* Commands in `[ ]` are optional
* `DAY` takes in the following inputs: `MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN` while `STARTTIME` and `ENDTIME` takes in the time in 24 hour format, for example 0800 for 8am.


Examples:
* `student -a -n John -c 12345678 -em john@mail.com -s TUE/1600/1800`<br>
  adds a student with the name John, contact number 12345678, email john@mail.com and a lesson every tuesday from 4pm to 6pm
* `student -a -n Barbara -c 12344321`<br>
  adds a student with the name Barbara and contact number 12344321

</details>
```

Which looks like this in Github

### closed:

[image]

### opened :

[image]

However, when I publish to `GitHub` pages, this is what it shows:

[image]

Basically, any markdown formatting within the drop-down does not render properly, how do I fix this?

I am not sure exactly what is used in the underlying, but I am pretty sure it is Jekyll.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by placing

markdown="1"

Inside the  tag.

So it looks something like below

```
<details markdown="1">
.. my stuff
</details>
```